# What is the best way to forward all requests on a certain port to another machine on the network?

Tags: networking, tcp, dns, port, iptables

I have two dedicated servers and no hardware firewall. I'd like to forward all requests that come into the primary server on port 1008 to be fulfilled by another dedicated server on the same network. I know I need to set up some kind of TCP proxy, but I first heard of IPTables yesterday. Any quick tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carson is right: put a bridging firewall between servers and clients. Shorewall (IP tables) can then redirect traffic to different ports and different machines.

With the firewall being a bridge, you don't have to change your network settings, yet the bridge interface has to be assigned one IP address of each network clients and servers are in. Else the redirection won't work.

Caveat: the machine where the connection originally was pointed to has to be online (means: its IP address has to be in use), else the redirect won't work.

If the redirection is meant as a means of failover for high-availability, I would consider a load balancer (cluster) instead of the firewall, which leads to linux virtual server (for a general approach) or to a load balancer software like Apache (with mod proxy_balancer), balance or pount (if only http request are to be balanced). There's also hardware appliances like from f5 for load balancing.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use something which is just a TCP proxy. It is possible to achieve this using iptables, but not easy.

It is easy to forward requests from A intended for B to C (using DNAT) but harder to get C's responses to go back to A via B (because DNAT does not change the sender address). A would then ignore the responses as they'd be coming from C rather than B.

Essentially the way of doing it would be to set up B as C's default gateway, and using forwarding, however, this places an additional point of failure in B; if B fails, C's outbound traffic (including responses to requests sent to C directly) would end up going down a black hole.

Using IPtables it is possible without this routing trick I think, but you'd need to have the same connection SNAT'd and DNAT'd, which is tricky at best.

Normally in such situations, most people put another host (firewall) in front of the two machines and have it make DNAT decisions - of course this introduces a point of failure as well, which is why in critical setups, the firewall typically has a rendundant backup (its configuration is synchronised and sometimes its connection tracking table is)

Answer (score 1):

First off I would recommend you get a firewall in place. I've used [Shorewall](http://www.shorewall.net/) for a long time to manage iptables and it is pretty easy to configure. Second if you use something like Shorewall there are easy [guides on how to do DNAT (port fowarding)](http://www.shorewall.net/two-interface.htm#DNAT).